# Create climatology from pandas dataframe (append the mean by day-of-year)

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

```
import pandas as pd
import pdb, random

dates = pd.date_range('1950-01-01', '1953-12-31', freq='D')
data  = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(len(dates))]
cum_data = pd.Series(data, index=dates)

cum_data.head()
    1950-01-01    310
    1950-01-02    477
    1950-01-03    401
    1950-01-04    896
    1950-01-05     65
...
    1951-01-01    320
...
    1952-01-01    330
...
    1953-01-01    340

# Compute climatology
cum_data.groupby([cum_data.index.month, cum_data.index.day]).mean()
```

I would like to calculate the climatology for this dataframe i.e. find the mean of all values corresponding to Jan 1st (for the years 1950 to 1953), and then append the mean value to the dataframe for the time period from Jan 1st 1954 to Dec 31st 1960. How do I do that?

The expected output should be the original dataset for the years 1950 to 1953. Jan 1st 1954 should be the average of Jan 1st of 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953. In this case:

```
    1954-01-01    325
...
    1955-01-01    325
...
...
    1960-01-01    325
```

So,
Jan 1st 1954 will equal Jan 1st 1955 ... Jan 1st 1960. This holds true for all the other days as well.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: This is simply computing the mean by day-of-year. That's basic aggregation. There are a ton of existing duplicate posts on that.

Comment: thanks smci, I am computing the mean by day-of-year, the question is how to append it to the existing dataframe for a new set of year (1954 to 1960)

Comment: I see, you want to compute one single mean by day-of-year across years 1950-3, then broadcast that mean to that day-of-year in each of the years 1954, 1955... 1960

Comment: @user308827 did you find the solution for the same question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `resample` function over a year period `AS`

```
In [8]: cum_data.resample('AS', how='mean')
Out[8]:
1950-01-01    502.169863
1951-01-01    503.698630
1952-01-01    503.185792
1953-01-01    504.961644
Freq: AS-JAN, dtype: float64
```

Store this result into `tmp`

```
In [9]: tmp = cum_data.resample('AS', how='mean')
```

Change the index to desired time range

```
In [10]: tmp.index = (pd.date_range('1954-01-01', '1957-01-01', freq='AS'))

In [11]: tmp
Out[11]:
1954-01-01    502.169863
1955-01-01    503.698630
1956-01-01    503.185792
1957-01-01    504.961644
Freq: AS-JAN, dtype: float64
```

Fill in with the daily dates too.

```
In [12]: tmp = tmp.reindex(pd.date_range('1954-01-01', '1957-12-31', freq='D')).ffill()

In [13]: tmp.head()
Out[13]:
1954-01-01    502.169863
1954-01-02    502.169863
1954-01-03    502.169863
1954-01-04    502.169863
1954-01-05    502.169863
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

And, then append to `cum_data`

```
In [14]: cum_data.append(tmp)
Out[14]:
1950-01-01    430
1950-01-02    125
1950-01-03    371
1950-01-04    906
1950-01-05    504
...
1957-12-28    504.961644
1957-12-29    504.961644
1957-12-30    504.961644
1957-12-31    504.961644
Length: 2922
```

Comment: thanks, however I want to append this to the original dataframe, and also update the time period from 1954 to 1960

Comment: also, I would like it to work for all days of the year and just not jan

Comment: thanks @John, this is almost perfect. The problem I am having is stretching the data all the way to the year 1960, can your solution do that?

Comment: Replace line 12 with `tmp = tmp.reindex(pd.date_range('1954-01-01', '1960-12-31', freq='D')).ffill()`

Comment: thanks, one more thing. I see that Jan 2nd 1954 is same as Jan 1st 1954. That should not be the case. Perhaps it is the ffill that is causing this?

Comment: Yes, how would you fill the daily values from year means?

Comment: I am not computing yearly means, I am computing the mean of the same date across years. E.g. March 1st 1954 is assigned : (Mar 1st 1950+Mar1st 1951+Mar1st 1952+Mar1st 1953)/4

Comment: Essentially you want to compute one single mean by day-of-year across years 1950-3, then broadcast that mean to each of the years 1954, 1955... 1960

Comment: @user308827 did u find the solution for your question ?